# How can I call functions defined in a Chrome Extension from regular websites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to make a website that is not part of the chrome plugin but rather just uses some API that the plugin exposes to it. Is this possible and if so, how do I do it? I googled this question and was unable to find anything.

I'm trying to use content scripts but nothing happens. Can someone explain what's wrong here?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Hello World Extension",
  "description": "This extension prints hello world.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://locahost:8888/*"],
      "js": ["EmotivAPI.js"]
     }
   ]
}
```

EmotivAPI.js

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();
console.log("Hello?");
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    // We only accept messages from ourselves
    if (event.source != window)
        return;

    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
        console.log("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
        port.postMessage(event.data.text);
        alert("recieved!");
    }
}, false);
```

js in the webpage

```
window.sayHello = function () {
        window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from webpage!" }, "*");
    }
    console.log('Emotiv extension loaded.');
}
```

I'm calling window.sayHello() from the console

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  I think those methods are held securely.  With that said, your plugin might be able to inject JS from the plugin into the loaded window, at which point you would be able to access it.  It's what, I assume, GreaseMonkey does in some cases.

Comment: you can use content-scripts/page action to match particular or wild card pattern for the url where your app will be hosted.

Comment: @Yoda I think this may be what I need. So instead of writing my javascript functions that I want the page to use in the extension pages, I need to put them in the content-scripts page. If the extension wants to send data to the content-script, I just need to pass it via a message. Do content-scripts run in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Content Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) can help you in this case.

The content script will be injected into a page:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"], // try with "http://localhost:*/*" or "http://localhost:*" 
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ]
```

If you want to inject the code only sometimes, use the permissions field instead

```
/* in manifest.json */
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
],
```

In you extension html file, you can then execute the script by:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

Comment: @user1274649 a good example is how rss feeds work. rss feed extensions monitor the page if they have a particular content/url, then they  execute the content-script js.

Comment: I updated my question with some code I tried but it did not work. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: got it working with http://*/* and run_at property but I would prefer to use http://localhost:8888/

Comment: @user1274649 does your code in EmotivAPI file executes, try logging something in console or by an alert? if not replace the matches value for content script to `http://*/*`.

Comment: @user1274649 check my answer- written some pattern in comments. does ur js executes now?

Comment: I'll give it a shot when i have the time. Thanks for your help. I think this will fix my problem